# Can i use jackson and xstream serializers for same event across mutiple services

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I have 2 spring boot micro-services **core** and **web**:

The **core** service reacts to some event (EmployeeCreatedEvent) which is triggered by **web**.
The **core** service is using jackson serializer to serialize commands, queries, events and messages whereas the **web** service is using xstream serializer.
i am getting below error in **core** while handling EmployeeCreatedEvent triggered by **web**:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (’<’ (code 60)): 
expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token ‘null’, ‘true’ or ‘false’)
```

i am using below properties (jackson for core and default for web):

```
axon.serializer.general = jackson/default
axon.serializer.events = jackson/default
axon.serializer.messages = jackson/default
```

can someone suggest whether it is ok to use different serializer for same event in different services.

Comment: I would say that it's not ok to use different formats for the same event/command. I would add that it's better to bite the bulllet and fix this now, and come up with a common serialisation for all events, rather than hack something to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Augusto here and you should make a decision about which serialization format you are going to use across all your services.

I am assuming you started with the default serializer (which is `XStream` and XML) and later on decided to move to `Jackson` (which is JSON).
In that case, there are 2 advices I can share with you:

- You can write a Custom Serializer which have both implementations and try with both of them and see which one works, for example trying with XML and fallbacking to JSON.
- Or you can have a `Component` which will listen to all `Event`s from your `EventStore`, deserialize them using `XStream` and write them back to another `EventStore` using `Jackson`. In this case, for this migration period, you will have this component using 2 Event Streams (one for each `EventStore`) but after the migration is done your whole `EventStore` will be in JSON. This requires some work but is the best approach in my opinion and will save you a lot of time and pain in the future.
  You can look more about configuring 2 sources [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors#configuring-processors).